# Possible performance enhancement for AbstractStringBuilder

Tags: java, performance, stringbuilder

I was doing tests with the Java StringBuilder, especially the replace(int, int, String) function which is implemented in the AbstractStringBuilder class as followed:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder replace(int start, int end, String str) {
    if (start < 0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
    if (start > count)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("start > length()");
    if (start > end)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("start > end");

    if (end > count)
       end = count;
    int len = str.length();
    int newCount = count + len - (end - start);
    if (newCount > value.length)
       expandCapacity(newCount);

    System.arraycopy(value, end, value, start + len, count - end);
    str.getChars(value, start);
    count = newCount;
    return this;
}
```

The Arraycopy function call does "move" parts the content of the value character array to make space for the later injected str content (str.getChars(value, start)). From my point of view, one should only do this arraycopy if the str length does not match the space to be overwritten in the character array anyways.

Clearly one is *very* desperate to consider this a performance issue, though making tests with bigger character arrays (>500k chars) and arraycopy in a StringBuilder replacement class leaded to measurable performance improvement.

Tested with java 6 on a Windows 32bit Platform an the same StringBuilder instance for some million replace calls.

Would you consider this to be unimportant, a bug or am I missing something completely?

Comment: unimportant, definitely.

Comment: Submit a request to Oracle/Sun and see what they say.  I don't think it's a "bug", because the code works.  Call it a possible enhancement and you might get further.  I'd also consider that you might be missing something completely.  You might be thinking about a single corner case that's not generally valid.  I don't have time to verify your train of thought right now.

Comment: I suspect `arraycopy` is smart enough to avoid unnecessary work, anyway; the only performance improvement would come from avoiding the checking needed to determine that the work is unnecessary. I think you have a point, actually.

Comment: I was doing tests with arraycopy. Replacing smaller arrays with themself has been faster than with bigger arrays. At least size of the array matters, independent of arraycopy to detect unneeded copies.

Comment: Not convinced this is an optimization.  I suspect that the added cost to the much more common case that you're _not_ copying onto the same location isn't worth the performance improvements in this rare case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass it as a request for enhancement.

Something like

```
if (end != start + len)
    System.arraycopy(value, end, value, start + len, count - end);
```

A further enhancement would be to change array copy.

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos,
                                    Object dest, int destPos,
                                    int length) {
    if (srcPos != destPos && length != 0)
       arraycopy0(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length);
```

}

```
private static native void arraycopy0(Object src,  int  srcPos,
                                    Object dest, int destPos,
                                    int length);
```